# How to set two defaultInterpreterPath simultaneously for two different remote locations in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, virtual-environment

I am working remotely on two computers through SSH. In each one of them I have a virtual environment that I want to use as 'defaultinterpreterPath' on VS code, but the respective paths are different. So if I set one by default it works fine, but each time I access the other computer I have to select the interpreter or change the settings.json file manually.

I tried using a list with two options like
`{ "python.defaultInterpreterPath": ["/.../username1/venv1/bin/python3", "/.../username2/venv2/bin/python3"], ... }`
but it did not work.

adding the second path to `"python.analysis.extraPaths":` did not work neither.